# How can I determine if a Perl function exists at runtime?

Tags: perl, introspection

I'm working on a test framework in Perl. As part of the tests, I may need to add precondition or postcondition checks for any given test, but not necessarily for all of them. What I've got so far is something like:

```
eval "&verify_precondition_TEST$n";
print $@ if $@;
```

Unfortunately, this outputs "Undefined subroutine &verify_precondition_TEST1 called at ..." if the function does not exist.

How can I determine ahead of time whether the function exists, before trying to call it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With defined:

```
if (eval "defined(&verify_precondition_TEST$n)") {
    eval "&verify_precondition_TEST$n";
    print $@ if $@;
}
else {
    print "verify_precondition_TEST$n does not exist\n";
}
```

**EDIT:** hmm, I only thought of eval as it was in the question but with symbolic references brought up with Leon Timmermans, couldn't you do

```
if (defined(&{"verify_precondition_TEST$n"}) {
    &{"verify_precondition_TEST$n"};
    print $@ if $@;
}
else {
    print "verify_precondition_TEST$n does not exist\n";
}
```

even with strict?

Comment: This is the wrong eval. You want block eval, not string eval. Plus testing if a function exists can be done with an eval anyway.

Comment: I need to use string eval because $n is not known at compile time.

Comment: No you don't. You need to use symbolic references. See my answer for an example of how to approach them.

Comment: You're right, defined is exempt from strict refs. However, calling a sub isn't. You have to either do 'no strict' or use an eval, the former being cleaner IMNSHO

Comment: Also, you need to use package name if the function is defined in some package... for example `use CGI; my $q=CGI->new; my @users = defined (&CGI::multi_param) ? $q->multi_param('u') : $q->param('u');`

Answer (score 43):

```
Package::Name->can('function')
```

or

```
*Package::Name::function{CODE}

# or no strict; *{ "Package::Name::$function" }{CODE}
```

or just live with the exception.  If you call the function in an eval and $@ is set, then you can't call the function.

Finally, it sounds like you may want Test::Class instead of writing this yourself.

Edit:  `defined &function_name` (or the `no strict; defined &{ $function_name }` variant), as mentioned in the other answers, looks to be the best way.  UNIVERSAL::can is best for something you're going to call as a method (stylistically), and why bother messing around with the symbol table when Perl gives you syntax to do what you want.

Learning++ :)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm doing this outside any package, so I get: Can't locate object method "can" via package "main". Also, I'm using an ancient version of Perl (5.002) in an environment where I have absolutely no Perl modules installed.

Comment: Whoa, 5.002?  I think that came out before I was born :)

Comment: Isn't 5.002 the one with all of the buffer overflow problems? :)

Comment: According to perlhist, 5.003 is 5.002 with security fixes.

Comment: (And, they didn't have UNIVERSAL:: back then, apparently.  Which is why main->can doesn't work; it works fine under 5.10.)

Comment: @Greg Hewgill  you are never outside of a package.  Try main->can("function")

Comment: @GregHewgill - i'm wondering about your environment. Can you please drop few words about it? It sounds as a __great__ example of using "ancient" platforms up to today...

Comment: @jm666: I think at the time it was some flavour of either OSF/1 or AIX. The Perl that was installed came with the OS and it wasn't worth the effort to attempt an upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. This checking is working very well in case of removing defined function

Answer (score 20):

```
sub function_exists {    
    no strict 'refs';
    my $funcname = shift;
    return \&{$funcname} if defined &{$funcname};
    return;
}

if (my $subref = function_exists("verify_precondition_TEST$n") {
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 (no strict is always better than string eval)

BTW, tiny typo: s/$functname/$funcname/

Comment: I'd write that as `no strict 'refs'` just to note to the reader that you're about to do some symbolic reference magic. :)

Answer (score 5):

I had used Leon's approach, but when I had multiple packages, it failed. I'm not sure precisely why; I think it relates to the propagation of scope between namespaces. This is the solution I came up with.

```
my %symbols = ();
my $package = __PACKAGE__; # bring it in at run-time
{
    no strict;
    %symbols = %{$package . "::"}; #S ee Symbol Tables on perlmod
}
print "$funcname not defined\n" if (!defined($symbols{$funcname});
```

References:
[__PACKAGE__](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) reference on the perlmod page.

[Packages/__PACKAGE__](http://perltraining.com.au/tips/2005-06-14.html)reference on Perl Training Australia.

Comment: The problem might be if you've tried to do directly like: `if ( defined &{$package . '::subname'} )`, but like this is should be fine: `my $subname = $package.'::sub_name'; if ( defined &{$subname} ) ... `